# Ktor Serializer for class 'Response' is not found

Tags: kotlin, serialization, ktor, ktor-client

Plugin and dependeny:

```
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization' version "$kotlin_version"
implementation "io.ktor:ktor-serialization:$ktor_version"
```

`Application` file:

```
fun main() {
    embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080, host = "0.0.0.0") {
        install(ContentNegotiation) {
            json()
        }

        userRouter()
    }.start(wait = true)
}
```

`UserRouter`:

```
fun Application.userRouter() {
    routing {
        get("/users/{id}") {
            val id = call.parameters["id"]?.toInt() ?: -1
            val user = User("Sam", "sam@gmail.com", "abc123")

            val response = if (id == 1) {
                Response("hahaha", false)
            } else {
                Response(user, true)        //< - here, use String type will work
            }

            call.respond(response)
        }
    }
}
```

`User`:

```
@Serializable
data class User(
    val name: String,
    val email: String,
    val password: String
)
```

`Response`:

```
@Serializable
data class Response<T>(
    val data: T,
    val success: Boolean
)
```

Logs:

```
2021-12-02 18:04:34.214 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-1] ERROR ktor.application - Unhandled: GET - /users/7
kotlinx.serialization.SerializationException: Serializer for class 'Response' is not found.
Mark the class as @Serializable or provide the serializer explicitly.
    at kotlinx.serialization.internal.Platform_commonKt.serializerNotRegistered(Platform.common.kt:91)
    at kotlinx.serialization.SerializersKt__SerializersKt.serializer(Serializers.kt:155)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that type for the `response` variable is `Response<out Any>` (the lowest common denominator between `String` and `User` types is `Any`) and the serialization framework cannot serialize the `Any` type.

Comment: The weird thing is, it works in this tutorial: https://youtu.be/uhNF4wK4hWU.

Comment: @SamChen, The tutorial is different, it uses two separate respond calls (with different parameter types). Respond here is reified so it actually captures the static type, which in the question case was the common denominator between both responses.

There are separate issues with returning variable types without discriminator, but that's a different discussion.

Answer (score 0):

That's werid, the following works, but to me they are just the same:

```
get("/users/{id}") {
    val id = call.parameters["id"]?.toInt() ?: -1
    val user = User("Sam", "sam@gmail.com", "abc123")

   /* val response = if (id == 1) {      //<- determine response here won't work, why?
        Response("hahaha", false)
    } else {
        Response(user, true)
    }

    call.respond(response)*/

    if (id == 1) {
        call.respond(Response("hahaha", false))
    } else {
        call.respond(Response(user, true))
    }
}
```

Comment: They are not the same. In this case the first `respond` receives a value of type `Response<String>` and the second respond receives a value of type `Response<User>`. The original case uses a single variable to hold both, and thus of type `Response<Any>`. Note that kotlinx.serialization is a static framework, using static types, not runtime types.

Comment: @Paul de Vrieze That helps, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should give a type to a generic when you set a nullable generic to null, otherwise, the plugin doesn't know how to serialize it.
for eg.

```kotlin
//define
@Serializable
data class Response<T>(
    val data: T?,
    val success: Boolean
)

///usage:
val response = Response<String>(null, false)
```